# Why do I get a warning when I use recursion in CUDA?

Tags: recursion, cuda

I have to solve a code problem on the gpu using **CUDA** but I always get a warning of **Stack size for "name of the function" cannot be statically determined**.

This is for a student project that I'm working on, the project is written in **C** using **CUDA 9.0** libraries and it's running on an **NVIDIA Quadro K5000 gpu**.
Every single thread must execute one function and, in this function, there are two recursive calls of the same function, the reason why I want to use those two recursive calls it's because it makes the code clean and simple for me, but if there is only one recursive call there isn't anymore the **Stack size** problem.

Here is the error I get every time I compile the code:

[image]

**CUDA** supports recursive function calls but I don't understand why it makes a problem when there are two recursive calls.

```
__device__ void bitonicMergeGPU(float *arr, int l, int indexT, int order) 
{
    int k,p;

    if(l > 1)
    {
        p = l/2;

        for(k=indexT;k<indexT+p;k++)
        {
            //Compare the values.
            compareAndExchange(arr,k,k+p,order);
        }

        //THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR

        bitonicMergeGPU(arr,p,indexT,order);
        bitonicMergeGPU(arr,p,indexT+p,order);
    }
}
```

I simply want to know if it is possible to solve the problem of the recursive calls.

Comment: I assume you've seen [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/524712/a-meaning-of-nvlink-warning-stack-size-for-entry-function-cannot-be-statically-determined/)

Comment: Hi @cleblanc thank you for answering me. I forgot to mention in my question that I have already tried to increase the Stack size by using the [cudaDeviceSetLimit](http://horacio9573.no-ip.org/cuda/group__CUDART__DEVICE_gb8a22e29cc297634b0702db0b69f59e7.html) but since the problem is in compile time I still didn't solved the problem by using this function. So by the post you sended to me I have to find a way to increase the stack size but it seems that it's possible to execute the code anyway since it's a warning.

Comment: Yes, it's only a warning.  I think your host driver needs to be sure to create a large enough stack for this recursion at run time.  Hopefully you have an upper bound of how many recursions there will be.

Comment: It's a warning, not an error.  If you use a function recursively, in most languages it will use more stack space as the recursion depth increases.  You need to account for this and provide enough stack space for the maximum recursion depth you anticipate.  There is usually no way to discover the maximum runtime recursion depth at compile time, and the warning is there to remind you of that.  And regardless of how much you increase the stack size, the warning will not go away.  The warning is there to let you know that it is your responsibility to make sure this works.

Comment: Thank you @RobertCrovella for answering my question. I always thinked that was an error but instead it's just a warning and I saw on the CUDA Manual that there is a function to increase the stack size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CUDA supports recursion.  When you use recursion in CUDA, this warning is expected, and there is no NVIDIA-documented way you can make the warning go away (except by not using recursion).

If you use a function recursively, in most languages it will use more stack space as the recursion depth increases.  This is true in CUDA as well. You need to account for this and provide enough stack space for the maximum recursion depth you anticipate. It is common practice to limit recursion depth, so as to prevent stack problems.

The compiler is unable to discover the maximum runtime recursion depth at compile time, and the warning is there to remind you of that.

Regardless of how much you increase the stack size, the warning will not go away. The warning is there to let you know that it is your responsibility to make sure your recursion design along with the stack space allocated will work correctly.  The compiler does not verify in any way that the amount of increase in stack size is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Using recursion in CUDA must be very careful. The recursion uses stack memory which has a limit of 512 KB. The default is usually 1KB which is easy to overflow and crashes the program. You can get the stack size per thread using cudaThreadGetLimit().

Suggestions:

1. Redesign the algorithm/function using a non-recursive approach. The efficiency is usually very similar.
2. Increase stack size per thread using cudaThreadSetLimit(), not exceed the limit, e.g. 512KB.

Comment: Hi @Charlie thank you for replying my post. Since this is a post of last year I didn't write that I have solved the problem, last year after two or three days from publishing this post, by not using the recursive approach and, as you wrote here, the efficiency is very similar. The problem was this, I wrote the algorithm of the [Bitonic Sort](https://tutorialspoint.dev/algorithm/sorting-algorithms/bitonic-sort), using the CUDA library, in a wrong way. Each sorting step uses half threads to do the sorting which is wrong because each step the number of threads to do the sort must me the same.

Comment: @Simone, thanks for the update. I am glad you have solved the problem.